# How to stop progress bar at 100% in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a `progress bar` using bootstrap when I do an `ajax` request. I am able to start the progress bar but the problem is I don't know a way to make it stop at 100% when the `ajax call` is `success`. Below are the codes that I make:

**html**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let percentValue = 0,
    progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    timer = setInterval(startBar, 500);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(){
        startBar();
      },
      success: function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      }).done(function(data){
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
      }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ){
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });

    function startBar(){
      percentValue += 25;
      progressBar.css("width", percentValue + "%").html(percentValue + "%");
    }
});
```

The result that I received is mostly it will stop at 75%. I am not making any upload. It just get a data from the server. How to make it stop at 100%?

Comment: Why can't you set the width in the success callback just as you do in `startBar()`?

Comment: Your startBar method needs to have a conditional that prevents the percentValue from going beyond 100.  And your success method needs a way to make the progress bar update to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The interval will start the progress bar loading, so you do not need to call it on beforeSend
- On success, if the percent value is less than 100, make it 75 so it will update on the next interval and end
- startBar method checks to see if the percent is less than 100.  If it is, it will update and continue.  Otherwise, if it has reached 100, it will terminate the interval

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let percentValue = 0,
        progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
        timer = setInterval(startBar, 500);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(){
        if (percentValue < 100) percentValue = 75;
      }
      }).done(function(data){
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
      }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ){
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });

    function startBar(){
      if (percentValue < 100) {
        percentValue += 25;
        progressBar.css("width", percentValue + "%").html(percentValue + "%");
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just want to know should I put tje startBar in the beforeSend function or I can just Make it before the ajax call?

Comment: @Khairul please reference my first bullet, :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your `startBar()` function when success:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let percentValue = 0,
    progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    timer = setInterval(startBar, 500);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(){
        startBar();
      },
      success: function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      }).done(function(data){
        alert("success");
        startBar();
        console.log(data);
      }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ){
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });

    function startBar(){
      percentValue += 25;
      progressBar.css("width", percentValue + "%").html(percentValue + "%");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let percentValue = 0,
    progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
  timer = setInterval(startBar, 500);

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c3f66243500002d2cec3954",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      startBar();
    },
    success: function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert("success");
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
  });

  function startBar() {
    if (percentValue < 100) {
      percentValue += 25;

    }
    progressBar.css("width", percentValue + "%").html(percentValue + "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```